# Alternative to hyperlink to navigate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hyperlink, wpf-4.0

I'm using WPF (.net 4.5 target) and while i'm quite used to WPF this is the first time i'm working with the page / navigation model.

I see that to navigate to a page i can do something very simple (use an hyperlink) however this is very far from what i want in terms of style (i'd rather start from a button). Is there an alternative to hyperlinks or is my best shot to go with a button + code behind to navigate?

My goal is to provide styled buttons with icons as hyperlinks within a uniformgrid that takes the whole page for the home page.

Comment: You can style a button however you want.  In WPF pretty much anything is a content control.

Comment: That's not the question at all, an hyperlink isn't a button and must be embeded in a textblock, i want something "like" a button with the functionality of an hyperlink, so far i did that with buttons and code behind but my question was, is there an alternative control that does the same as hyperlink, but isn't an inline text content but a plain contentcontrol

Comment: Then you need to work on your question.  "provide styled buttons with icons"

Comment: You need to read the whole question to get context, that's my visual goal, so on 1 hand buttons are my visual goal, on the other hand hyperlink is my functional goal, i'm looking for something that brings both (a button look with hyperlink functionality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Silverlight/WP, there is [`HyperlinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which is exactly what you're asking for, but apparently that does not exist in WPF.  So, it seems that your best bet would be to use the regular Button, along with [`NavigationService.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in its Command.  So, something like this:

```
<Button Content="Navigate" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="/Views/SomePage.xaml" />
```

Then `NavigateCommand` would be a standard DelegateCommand, using the parameter as the URI:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(url => {
            var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
            NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
        });
    }
}
```

---

You may instead want to write your own version of HyperlinkButton, which would go something like this:

```
public class HyperlinkButton : Button
{
    public string NavigateUri { get; set; }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (NavigateUri != null)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(NavigateUri, UriKind.Relative);
            NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have such a solution working but was really hoping there was something built in, yea HyperlinkButton seems like it would've fit perfectly, they went so wrong forking SL & WPF early on and not having one be a superset of the other in my opinion, it's such a mess :(